# How to stop ReadXL from skipping empty columns

Tags: r, readxl

I have an excel file that has multiple tables on one sheet. I am trying to use `readxl::read.xlsx()` to read in specific ranges for each data frame from excel but it keeps skipping the first few columns. I assume its because of the formatting of the separate tables on the sheet.

I have uploaded a copy of data I'm trying to import here: https://filebin.net/lllptc6z59uzgjta/Capture.PNG?t=twuqxjzp

I've tried using `XLConnect`,`gdata`, and `openxlsx` but get the same result each time.

To get the first table I try:

```r
df <- read_excel("students.xlsx",
                 range = cell_limits(c(6, 3), c(7, 6)))
```

But get

```r
New  Current Total ...3  ...4
 17   39            NA    NA
```

printed out instead of the desired output

```r
Previous Total  Previous New    New  Current Total
 10              22              17   39
```

Comment: You have your rows and columns switched.  Try `cell_limits(c(6,3), c(7,6))`

Comment: Hi, sorry that was a copying issue - I've update it now. @TylerSmith